# Error with pycripto and AWS-Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pycrypto

I'm trying to use pycrypto and lambda service, but every time that i run my script lambda service return:

> Unable to import module 'service': /var/task/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.so:
>   invalid ELF header

I don't know why is happen if someone have the same problem, please help me.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, had to build my deployable zip on a Linux VM.

As alex-luminul [comments](https://github.com/fugue/credstash/issues/58#issuecomment-224282388) in this [issue](https://github.com/fugue/credstash/issues/5), it may be due to the OSX-compatible shared library _AES.so being sent to Lambda, where Lambda requires Linux compatible shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There are some people who have pre-compiled some python packages for use in AWS Lambda. For example the pip package [lambda_packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lambda_packages) and a GitHub repository called [awslambda-pycrypto](https://github.com/Doerge/awslambda-pycrypto).

I picked the latter since I only needed PyCrypto in my function. To use it, I downloaded the awslambda-pycrypto repository and then put the files in a directory named "modules", and then I loaded the code like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "./modules")
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

You then have to zip the directory that contains your function and upload it to Lambda.